# SQL statement takes huge amount of time, is it possible optimize it?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

This is my SQL query with which I get all the duplicates, but one(the newest one):

```
SELECT d.C_ContactID, d.C_EmailAddress, d.C_DataSourceID, d.C_DateCreated 
FROM duplicates as d 
WHERE d.C_DateCreated !=(select max(d2.C_DateCreated) 
FROM duplicates d2 
WHERE d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId)
```

Is it possible to optimize it somehow? Unfortunately in 300 000 records it takes +- 40minutes.

Method where the query is:

```
public ArrayList<Record> get() throws SQLException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    Statement st = DBConnect.DBC.con.createStatement();
    String sql = ("select d.C_ContactID, d.C_EmailAddress, d.C_DataSourceID, 
d.C_DateCreated "
            + "from duplicates as d "
            + "where d.C_DateCreated !=(select max(d2.C_DateCreated) "
            + "from duplicates d2 where d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId)");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    DBConnect.DBC.con.commit();
    while (rs.next()) {

        int contactID = rs.getInt("C_ContactID");
        String email = rs.getString("C_EmailAddress");
        String dataSourceID = rs.getString("C_DataSourceID");
        String dateCreated = rs.getString("C_DateCreated");
        duplicate = new Record(contactID, email, dataSourceID, dateCreated);
        duplicates.add(duplicate);
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();

    return duplicates;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on that table?

Comment: Which flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: What is your RDBMs? Plus add the execution plan to your question.

Comment: What do you mean by indexes? I have primary unique key contact ID. Did you mean that?

Comment: What is execution plan? I will edit a question with the explanation where does the query execute.

Comment: @OndrejTokar: This is one index. Read up on indexes to understand what  they are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would start by creating an index on `duplicates(C_DataSourceId, C_DateCreated)`:

```
create index duplicates_DataSourceId_DateCreated on duplicates(C_DataSourceId, C_DateCreated);
```

If you are using a database that supports window functions, then I would rephrase this as:

```
SELECT d.C_ContactID, d.C_EmailAddress, d.C_DataSourceID, d.C_DateCreated 
FROM (select d.*, max(C_DateCreated) over (partition by C_DataSourceId) as maxdc
      from duplicates d 
     ) d
WHERE d.C_DateCreated <> maxdc;
```

It is worth doing the comparison, because sometimes window functions have efficient implementations.

And, if you have the index, a slightly more efficient version of your query is:

```
SELECT d.C_ContactID, d.C_EmailAddress, d.C_DataSourceID, d.C_DateCreated 
FROM duplicates d
WHERE EXISTS (select 1
              from duplicates 2
              where d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId and
                    d2.C_DateCreated > d.C_DateCreated
             );
```

This says to get all rows from duplicates where there is another row (with the same source) that has a bigger date created.  The slight advantage is that this doesn't have to look at *all* the values to get the `max()`.  It only has to find the first one.  The major performance improvement will be the composite index.

Comment: would you mind telling me the exactly how to do the index, since I have no idea what it is yet, but I will check it. Thanks and also I will mark it as answer.

Comment: I tried your query and probably my SQLite does not support window functions. But thanks for that indexing.

Comment: Your whole answer is perfect and I will mark it as right, thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure it's worth creating an index on multiple columns in that query? Not sure [the planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) will make use of it.

Comment: @OndrejTokar, I'd suggest creating two indexes instead (one for C_DataSourceId and one for C_DateCreated).

Comment: You might be right and when I have time, I will try it but so far this works perfectly it is instead 40 minutes just 20 seconds :). Anyway very thanks to you too.

Comment: @Bruno . . . The correct index for this query is a composite index with both columns in that order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah, I guess it depends if we talk about the initial query in the question or your last query (sorry I hadn't noticed the edit). The index you suggested can indeed by useful with your version. I think having `C_DateCreated` in that index probably won't make a difference in the initial query (although there should still be a reasonably speed up for being able to use `C_DataSourceId` anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Create index for the columns C_DateCreated and C_DataSourceId. This will reduce the time to execute the query. Refer this link to know how to create indices. 
 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm

Comment: The question is tagged with SQLite, not MySQL. The index and planner will behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL the answer would look like this, but I don't think SQLite supports window functions (leaving the answer intact for posterity though):

You can use a window function to label each row with it's position in the group of common C_DataSourceIDs, then with a CTE select the rows that aren't in position 1 like this.

```
with ordered as (
    select
        d.C_ContactID,
        d.C_EmailAddress,
        d.C_DataSourceID,
        d.C_DateCreated,
        row_number() over (
            partition by
                d.C_DataSourceID
            order by
                d.C_DateCreated
        ) as rownum
    from
        duplicates
) select
    C_ContactID,
    C_EmailAddress,
    C_DataSourceID,
    C_DateCreated
from
    ordered
where
    rownum != 1;
```

With an index on `(C_DataSourceID, C_DateCreated)` this will only need a single pass over the table instead of a self join that you have in your query.

Comment: Are you sure SQLite supports CTEs?

Comment: Bah, missed the tag and thought I was looking at C#, hence assumed T-SQL. Newer SQLite does support CTEs, not sure about window functions though.

Comment: Ah yes, [you're right](http://sqlite.org/lang_with.html). I can't see anything about window functions, though.